# Regex select all anchors except some

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I need to remove all anchors (anchor text remains) from the string except those anchors that have `href="/"`

This is example text:

`Fusce imperdiet nulla ut sapien aliquet, congue varius dui consectetur. <a href="/">This link remains</a> et blandit nisl. Curabitur euismod volutpat urna, eget dignissim libero cursus rhoncus. Nulla ac test sollicitudin <a href="test">link from this text should be removed</a>. Maecenas sodales vel lorem eu placerat.`

Here is regex that I think should work (using negative lookahead):

`/<a.*?(?!href=["']\/["'])>(.*?)</a>/gi`

Yet it selects both anchors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try regex `<a(?!.*href=["']\/["']).*?>(.*?)<\/a>`

The negative lookahead `(?!.*href=["']\/["'])` won't capture the tag with `href="/"`

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/2I7UCQ/4)

Comment: this regex captures in $1 `href="test">link from this text should be removed`. For replacing i need to capture only `link from this text should be removed`

Comment: Edited. Now the `$1` will capture only `link from this text...`